# is remember keyword enough for caching paginated query results

Tags: php, caching, laravel

I have the following query:

```
$posts = Post::where('category_id', '=', $category->id)
        ->where('isOk', '=', True)
        ->orderBy('submitTimestamp', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20);
```

If I insert `->remember(10)` to the query, would the caching of requested page be performed successfully?

Secondly, how can I make forget all cached pages (of a category) when (for example) a new post is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to flush all of a certain type (such as all posts), you amy want to look into cache tags instead of using the eloquent cache.  This will give you more control and allow you to flush groups of cached sets.

**From the Laravel documentation:**

```
// Setting tagged cached item in 'people' > 'authors' 
Cache::tags('people', 'authors')->put('John', $john, $minutes);

// Retrieving a cached item from a tag of 'people' > 'artists'
$anne = Cache::tags('people', 'authors')->get('John');

// Removing all items with a tag of 'people'
Cache::tags('people')->flush();
```

**More on cache tags:**
http://laravel.com/docs/cache#cache-tags

Comment: But I am not sure I can use Cache:: for paginated query results. How can I cache paginated queries with Cache::?

Comment: If you cache the entire query result, you can manually paginate it after pulling it from cache with the paginator class `$users = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);`

Comment: <b>Ne yapayım ben.</b>